# How to URL rewrite formaction for button using IIS 8.5

Tags: url-rewriting, reverse-proxy, asp.net-core-2.2, iis-8.5

I have a ASP.NET Core 2.2 website running on my server

```
mydomain.com/foo
```

which points at

```
localhost:83
```

Everything seems to get rewritten using the URL Rewrite rule:

```
<outboundRules>
    <rule name="ReverseProxyOutboundRule" stopProcessing="false">
        <match filterByTags="A, Area, Base, Form, Frame, Head, IFrame, Img, Input, Link, Script" pattern="^(http)?(s)?(://)?localhost:83/(.*)" />
        <action type="Rewrite" value="http{R:1}://mydomain.com/foo/{R:4}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Relative" enabled="true">
        <match filterByTags="A, Area, Base, Form, Frame, Head, IFrame, Img, Input, Link, Script" pattern="^/(.*)$" />
        <action type="Rewrite" value="/foo/{R:1}" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/foo(.?)" />
        </conditions>
    </rule>
</outboundRules>
```

Well almost everything, except my `<button>`:

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" formaction="/dummy/mypage?handler=Delete">Delete</button>
```

which I expected should look like:

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" formaction="/foo/dummy/mypage?handler=Delete">Delete</button>
```

I have tried to add my button as a `custom tag`

```
<outboundRules>
    <rule name="ReverseProxyOutboundRule" stopProcessing="false">
        <match filterByTags="A, Area, Base, Form, Frame, Head, IFrame, Img, Input, Link, Script, CustomTags" customTags="Misc" pattern="^(http)?(s)?(://)?localhost:83/(.*)" />
        <action type="Rewrite" value="http{R:1}://mydomain.com/foo/{R:4}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Relative" enabled="true">
        <match filterByTags="A, Area, Base, Form, Frame, Head, IFrame, Img, Input, Link, Script, CustomTags" customTags="Misc" pattern="^/(.*)$" />
        <action type="Rewrite" value="/foo/{R:1}" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/foo(.?)" />
        </conditions>
    </rule>
    <customTags>
        <tags name="Misc">
            <tag name="button" attribute="formaction" />
        </tags>
    </customTags>
</outboundRules>
```

But it doesn't seem to do anything for me.

I actually expected the URL Rewrite to automatically support rewriting of `<button>`'s.

Can anyone tell what is missing here?

---

**Update**:
Added a relative rule which I didn't see the relevance of. The issue is still the same, the `formaction` on my `<button>` elements doesn't get rewritten.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is something wrong with your url rewrtie rule pattern.

I suggest you could try to use below url rewrite rule and test again.

```
        <outboundRules>
            <rule name="aa">
                <match filterByTags="CustomTags" customTags="MSC" pattern="/dummy/mypage" />
                <action type="Rewrite" value="/foo/dummy/mypage?handler=Delete" />
            </rule>
            <customTags>
                <tags name="MSC">
                    <tag name="button" attribute="formaction" />
                </tags>
            </customTags>
        </outboundRules>
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit regarding why my rewrite pattern is wrong? It does seem to work for everything else on my site - just not `formaction`s in my `button`s.

Comment: Since your url rewrite rule contains the "?" in the parttern, this is the reason why your rule doesn't work. In regex the ?  is regard as "mark indicates zero or one occurrences of the preceding element".

Comment: I don't understand why the ?'s in the pattern should affect this. I do however see, that I omitted a rule for relative paths, which I have now included. The first rule I need to map to from port 83 to `foo`. The second is to rewrite relative urls in case the request comes from `foo`.